# Sharepoint issue when trying to get data from API

Tags: sharepoint-online

When doing a GET call to the List API from JavaScript

`"/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Listeditems')/Items?$top = 250"`

We are getting only default 100 values.

There are about 210 values. How can I show all the values?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a typing mistake.

Remove space before and after `=` sign.

Refer below line. It will work.

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Listeditems')/Items?$top=250
```

Comment: No. i am getting the same default (100) items.

Comment: Yes. Because by SharePoint REST api you can get `100` items only by default. However you can get more than `100` items using `$top`. But in your case you have added extra space before and after the `=` sign. SO it just ignores the `$top` and returns default `100` items.

Comment: Just try to remove the extra space. And check again ..

Comment: I ran the script which you provided /_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Listeditems')/Items?$top=250   but getting 100 items only

Comment: Did you get any error ??

Comment: no error. but I am getting still 100 items only

Comment: Can you please add full code snippet of REST call in your question ..

Comment: Try add `$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE` to your call